# php how to get __DIR__ of child class

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes in separate folders

```
class Parent
{
    public $path = null;

    function  __construct()
    {
        $this->path = __DIR__;
    }
}
```

and

```
class Child extends Parent
{

}
```

So when I create an instance of Child:

```
$child = new Child();
echo $child->path
```

I get a path to Parent. What I actually want is to get path to Child. I cannot modify Child class.

Is it possible?

Comment: Don't think this can be done.  Why do you need to know the directory of the child?  Why can't you modify it?

Comment: tandu, I cannot modify Childs, cause they are added as extensions by users. And it would be bad to force users to add this __DIR__ thing into every class they create. Parent here represents basic functionality needed by core program so it can autoload resources stored in Child's directory. So core program autoloads all user defined Childs and loads associated resources automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP \_\_DIR\_\_ evaluated runtime (late binding)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100689/php-dir-evaluated-runtime-late-binding)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get use [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to get what you're looking for:

```
$child = new Child();
$class_info = new ReflectionClass($child);
echo dirname($class_info->getFileName());
```

Comment: If that works, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkbox. That will remove this from the "unanswered questions" list.

Comment: I already did that, but it seems that yesterday glitch at stackoverflow rolled it back..

Comment: Check this out: `$class_info = new ReflectionClass($this);`

Comment: Keep in mind that Reflection should not be used in production because it is slow as hell.