# PHP __DIR__ evaluated runtime (late binding)?

Tags: php, inheritance, dir, late-binding

Is it somehow possible to get the location of PHP file, evaluated at runtime? I am seeking something similar to the magic constant `__DIR__`, but evaluated at runtime, as a late binding. Similar difference with `self` and `static`:

```
__DIR__ ~ self
  ???   ~ static
```

My goal is defining a method in an abstract class, using `__DIR__` which would be evaluated respectively for each heir class. Example:

```
abstract class Parent {
  protected function getDir() {
    // return __DIR__; // does not work
    return <<I need this>>; // 
  }
}

class Heir extends Parent {
  public function doSomething() {
    $heirDirectory = $this->getDir();
    doStuff($heirDirectory);
  }
}
```

Obviously, this problem occurs only if `Parent` and `Heir` are in different directories. Please, take this into account. Also, defining `getDir` over and over again in various Heir classes does not seem to be and option, that's why we have inheritance...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the following code in getDir method of Parent class

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
$filename = $reflector->getFileName();
return dirname($filename);
```

Your parent class will look like this

```
abstract class Parent {
    protected function getDir() {
        $reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
        $filename = $reflector->getFileName();
        return dirname($filename);
    }
}
```

Hoping it will help.

Comment: This is cool... Anything else, people? The cleaner design the better.

Comment: You can also use ReflectionObject: 
`return dirname(new \ReflectionObject($this))->getFileName());`